# Code dynamic any chart headmap risk matrix

Tags: javascript, anychart

I would like with this code, create the maps dynamically (i.e. without using var 1, var 2, var 3, etc.) I want to make the creations dynamically.

```
                var heatMaRiesgoInherente = dataSetRiesgoInherente.mapAs({ x: [4], y: [3], value: [0], heat: [0], fill: [1] });
                // Crea el stage con el elemento container
                var stage = acgraph.create("container");
                // helper function to setup same settings for all six charts
                var setupChartSettings = function (chart) {
                    chart.container(stage);
                    chart.padding([1, 10, 5, 10]).margin(0);
                    //chart.interactivity().selectionMode("none");
                    //Activo texto en los vectores
                    chart.xAxis(true);
                    //Color de Borde 
                    chart.stroke("#D8D8D8");
                    //D8D8D8
                    //E6E6E6
                    chart.xAxis().staggerMode(false);
                    //Texto en el vector Y
                    chart.yAxis().stroke('#4195EE').ticks().enabled(false);
                    //Texto en el vector X
                    // Quita los labels dentro de las cajas de texto
                    //chart.labelsDisplayMode('drop');
                    chart.labels().enabled(false);
                    // Aca habilito los Tooltip
                    chart.tooltip(true);
                    chart.tooltip().title().useHtml(true);
                      // Creates el mapa para el Riesgo Inherente
                var menChart = anychart.heatMap(heatMaRiesgoInherente);
                //Titulo
                menChart.title().text('Mapa de Calor de Riesgo Inherente');
                //Tamaños de los cuadros
                menChart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "50%");
                //Asigna la configuracion
                setupChartSettings(menChart);
                menChart.draw();
```

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate your question. It is not clear what you want to do dynamically and what problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find out how to create a several heat map chart from one [data 
set](http://docs.anychart.com/latest/Working_with_Data/Using_Data_Sets):

```
  var data = anychart.data.set([
    ["Quarter 1",  'Mobile',  23,  28],
    ["Quarter 2",  'Mobile',  21,  26],
    ["Quarter 1",  'Desktop',  19,  26],
    ["Quarter 2",  'Desktop',  21,  27],
    ["Quarter 1",  'WebMail',  22,  28],
    ["Quarter 2",  'WebMail',  25,  27]
  ]);

stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

var dataSet = data.mapAs({
  x: [0],
  y: [1],
  heat: [2]
});

var heatmap_1 = anychart.heatMap(dataSet);

  heatmap_1.container(stage);
  heatmap_1.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "50%");

heatmap_1.draw();

var dataSet = data.mapAs({
  x: [0],
  y: [1],
  heat: [3]
});

var heatmap_2 = anychart.heatMap(dataSet);
  heatmap_2.container(stage);
  heatmap_2.bounds(0, "50%", "100%", "50%");
    heatmap_2.draw();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anycharts/g4ex62h0/

This example illustrates how you can create the heat map matrix, as you can see, using this way or modify it, you can create the necessary amount of heat maps, all you need is to optimize loop, because it is simple, just for illustration of the point:
http://jsfiddle.net/anycharts/txkkdwmx/

It illustrates the idea that you can pass some parameter and create heat maps, e.g. in the loop, before it won’t be enough. Also, you can define the large data set at the beginning and just map it for each of chart.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi..
Yes, I understand perfectly, however, I do not want to create:
Var heatmap_1
Var heatmap_2
Var heatmap_3
Var heatmap_n ...

What I want is to dynamically create those "var" through a cycle or an iteration, I explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create several charts from one data set in the loop, like:

```
          var dataSet = data.mapAs({
            x: [0],
            y: [1],
            heat: [count]
          });
          count++;
          var chart = anychart.heatMap(dataSet);
          chart.container(stage);
```

All you need - is to map the data in the appropriate way. See this example, it illustrates the point: http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/2/


I have a problem, apply the same example, and continue giving problems, because it draws on, ie draws the same, which is wrong.
Could you send me an example with this data to show 4 different graphs?